# C# Iterate List<string> and create object with data on specific index

Tags: c#, .net, list, loops, object

I have a List with lenght of N containing data for x amount of Products. This data I recieve from a text file. The data is structured like this:

```
0: <Amount of products (int)>
1: <Product 1 Description (string)>
2: <Product 1 Quantity (int)>
3: <Product 1 Price (double)>
4: <Product 1 Tax (double)>
...: Same for Product 2 (if any)
```

Every product in the list consists of 4 rows, as presented above. After the last row, there will be data for the next product (if index 0 > 1).
Now I need to iterate this list and create Product-objects with this data. Product is a class I've created and contains all the necessary properties to represent a product.

At the moment I have this, but I don't know how to continue from here:

```
private Cart GetProductsFromArray(List<string> array, int amount)
        {
            Cart cart = new Cart();
            for(int i = 0; i <= array.Count; i++)
            {
                Product temp = new Product();


                cart.Add(temp);
            }
            return cart;
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea of how I can solve this?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with sample inputs (in code) and explicit expectations of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works.

Beware this won't work if the file isn't formatted correctly (4 lines per product).

If the first line of `intput` is the number of products you can skip it with `int i = 1` instead in the for loop.

```
const int LinesPerProduct = 4;

private Cart GetProductsFromArray(List<string> input, int amount)
{
    var cart = new Cart();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i += LinesPerProduct)
    {
        var temp = new Product
        {
            Description = input[i];
            Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(input[i + 1]);
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(input[i + 2]);
            Tax = Convert.ToDouble(input[i + 3]);
        }
        cart.Add(temp);
    }
    return cart;
}
```